# jquery - finding the first select that has the first value selected?

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

I've got a number of select dropdowns, and the first value of all is empty (ie "").  What is the best way of selecting the FIRST select whose value is ""?   I've been trying things like

```
$j("[id*='user'] option[value='']").first().prop("selected", true);
```

But that's setting it vs looking for one that matches.

(ALL the ids start with 'user'; I need to find the first user select that has an empty value...)

Comment: But given that all select elements have an option with a `defaultSelected` property, you might find that this is just the same as finding the first select element regardless of user-selections.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want the select element, you can try [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

```
$j("[id*='user']").has('option[value=""]:selected').first()
```

Try

```js
$("[id*='user']").has('option[value=""]:selected').first().css({
    "color": 'red',
    "border-color": 'green'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="user-1">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option selected="selected">1</option>
</select>
<select id="user-2">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option selected="selected">1</option>
</select>
<select id="user-3">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
<select id="user-4">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
<select id="user-5">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option selected="selected">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @aldanux copy paste mistake... fixed

Comment: +1 Although this works, the `select` colour does not change for me in Chrome (Its fine in FF). Browsers are inconsistent with `select` styling so might I suggest that you update your example to include restyling the border too (which *does* show in Chrome) eg: `$("[id*='user']").has('option[value=""]:selected').first().css({'border-color':'red','color':'red'})`

Comment: Cool. Interestingly in Chrome (os-x) the CSS color does change now you've set a border too - but without changing the border it does not. Odd (and probably documented somewhere) ;)

Comment: @Moob my chrome(windows 7) is working fine without border color

Answer (score 1):

You need to use start with jquery selector i.e. `[id^=startwithid]` to get all ids start with user, see below code

```
$j("[id^='user'] option[value=]:selected").first().parent();
```

Or best way to use `:has` like below

```
$j("[id^='user']:has(option[value=]:selected)").first();
```

Comment: this will give the object of option. not select element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:has` selector to find select having option value `""` as selected:

```
$j("[id*='user']:has(option[value='']:selected)").first();
```

or

```
$j("[id*='user']:has(option[value='']:selected):eq(0)");
```